# How Does the Trimble Catalyst Work

Tags: qgis, gps, android, trimble, tablet

Does anyone have an idea as to how the Trimble Catalyst works?
https://catalyst.trimble.com/index.html

Where can we find specifications of the DA1 antenna?

I don't understand how they have achieved centimeter accuracy with a smartphone and "simple" antenna.

Comment: The antenna gets real time corrections http://www.trimble.com/gps_tutorial/howgps-error.aspx

Comment: But this is pretty simple antenna, for RTK positioning there are more complicated receivers.

Comment: RTK and GNSS are not the same.  The antenna is receiving directed positions

Comment: Yes, but before you sent first GGA message you need to have fixed coordinates with 'good accuracy', so base station/CORS network or in this case Trimble network will provide VRS corections. If you have pretty bad antenna it's really hard to achieve good accuracy despite you will use DGPS or RTK corrections.

Comment: You are confusing technologies realtime corrected positions is a different animal  maybe this article can help http://www.elecdata.com/blog/differential-correction-sources-sbas-rtk-base-stations-and-real-time-gnss-networks/ I'm not sure what a "simple" antenna is size and capability are not proportional

Comment: Ok, I understand what is DGPS, RTK, NRTK,VRS and etc..but this is probably some fusion from multiple techniques.

Answer (score 1):

It uses GNSS and carrier phase DGPS to get centimeter level accuracy.  You do not need to setup base stations with this method as you would with RTK. From there spec sheet in the link the OP provided there are several levels of precision available: meter and submeter use Satelite based corrections and Decimeter and Precision use real-time post processing.

- Meter -Worldwide with data connection; in most of the world via RTX Satellite delivered corrections
- SubMeter - Worldwide with data connection; in most of the world via
  RTX Satellite delivered corrections
- Decimeter - Data connection required.
- Precision - Data connection required.